# LLDB : Tab completion after user defined aliases?

Tags: debugging, lldb

Uding `lldb` I defined the following alias : `command alias bfn breakpoint set -n %1`

Sadly, it does not allow Tab completion as the regular command does. It's a pity because all the time gained in typing the command is lost typing whole identifiers that are sometimes quite complex.

Nevertheless, buit-in aliases allow for completion so I am hoping there's a way to achieve the
same behaviour for user defined aliases.

Are you aware of any solutions to this problem ?

Thansk in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with completion in option slots in aliases.  The completions work for arguments.  I think that’s what you are seeing, not that there’s different behaviors for “internal” and “user” aliases (there isn’t actually such a distinction)…

Every option has its own completer, and lldb isn’t figuring out which slot the positional argument resolves to before handling the completion.

Please file a bug about this with the bugs.llvm.org bug tracker. This should be possible, and would certainly be convenient.

Comment: I followed your advice and filed a bug : https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50184